# Help to prove $(A \times B)\cup (C \times D) \subseteq (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove $(A \times B)\cup (C \times D) \subseteq (A\cup C) \times (B\cup D)$

My attempt:

$\begin{align} 
(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) & \Rightarrow & (x,y) \in (A \times B) \vee (x,y( \in (C \times D) \\
& \Rightarrow & (x \in A \wedge y\in B) \vee (x \in C \wedge y \in D) \\
& \Rightarrow & (x \in A \wedge y \in B \vee x \in C) \wedge (x \in A \wedge y \in B \vee y \in D)
\end{align}$

I know that the last implication is correct but I don't think it helps in the proof. I don't know what else to do.

How do I complete this proof and what is the strategy behind it (so that I can tackle similar proofs in the future)? Also, in this case, how do I proof that the two sets are not equal? Since the given statement is true, I would expect the chain of implications to be reversible too and hence the two sets are equal.

Comment: The two sets are in general not equal. $$[-1,0]\times [-1,0] \cup [0,1]\times [0,1] \subsetneq [-1,1]\times [-1,1].$$ Therefore don't expect all arrows to be reversible.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283777/is-it-always-true-that-a-1-cup-a-2-times-b-1-cup-b-2-a-1-times-b-1-cu (However, I would expect that this question has already been asked - but I was not able to find a duplicate...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one more round of distribution. From this:

$$(x \in A \wedge y \in B) \vee (x \in C \wedge y \in D)$$

If you fully distribute to conjunctive normal form, you get this:

$$(x \in A \vee x \in C) \wedge (x \in A \vee y \in D) \wedge (y \in B \vee x \in C) \wedge (y \in B \vee y \in D)$$

$$\Rightarrow (x \in A \vee x \in C) \wedge (y \in B \vee y \in D)$$

Comment: how did you reason that the implication is true? Did you do a truth table or something else? And how would you show that the two sets are not equal?

Comment: From $P \wedge Q$ you can always infer $P$. If "it's raining" and "my cup is yellow", you can infer "it's raining". In this case, there were four propositions connected with $\wedge$, and I just dropped two of them. (This is called "conjunction elimination", by the way.)

As for how you would show the two sets are not equal, this was given in a comment. Make a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D)$.

That means either $x \in (A \times B)$ or $x \in (C \times D)$.

Without loss of generality, let's say $x \in (A \times B)$.

Let's rewrite: $x=(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$

Notice that $A \subseteq A \cup C$ and $B \subseteq B \cup D$, and so $x_1 \in A \cup C$ and $x_2 \in B \cup D$.

It follows that $x \in (A \cup C)\times(B \cup D)$.

The strategy for proving $A \subseteq B$ is to show that if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$.

To show that $A=B$, you need to show that if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$, and also if $x \in B$ then $x \in A$. This is the main strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I only add a few lines to what you has so far:

$\begin{align} 
(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cup (C \times D) & \Rightarrow & (x,y) \in (A \times B) \vee (x,y) \in (C \times D) \\
& \Rightarrow & (x \in A \wedge y\in B) \vee (x \in C \wedge y \in D) \\
& \overset{(*)}\Rightarrow & (x\in A \lor x\in C) \land (y\in B\lor y\in D) \\
& \Rightarrow & (x\in(A\cup C)) \land (y\in B\cup D) \\
& \Rightarrow & (x,y)\in (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)
\end{align}$

With the exception of the implication denoted by (*), it is just rewriting the definitions. (Where can we get from what we assume using the definition? How can we get to the last line, which is what we need?)

So now the only question is whether this implication is also true and whether you can explain, why it is true.

---

Other possibility: You could try to show that $(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D) = A\times B\cup A\times D\cup C\times B\cup C\times D$.