# Cartesian product of two unions of sets of sets $\subseteq$ union of products of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

I'm reading the book "The Foundations of Mathematics” by Ian Stewart and David Tall, and I am puzzled about one of exercises:

> **Chapter 4. Exercise 2.** Given $S$ and $T$ are sets of sets, prove that 
>   $$\left(\bigcup S\right) \times \left(\bigcup T\right) \subseteq \bigcup \{ X \times Y \mid X \in S, Y \in T \}$$

I can write the LHS as
$$\left(\bigcup S\right) \times \left(\bigcup T\right) = (S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup \ldots \cup S_n ) \times (T_1 \cup T_2 \cup T_3 \cup \ldots \cup T_n) $$

where each $S_i\in S$ and $T_i\in T$. Also, the RHS is

$$ \bigcup \{ X \times Y \mid X \in S, Y \in T \} = (S_1 \times T_1) \cup (S_1 \times T_2) \cup \ldots \cup (S_1 \times T_n) \cup (S_2 \times T_1) \cup \ldots \cup (S_2 \times T_n) \cup \ldots \cup (S_n \times T_n) $$

If I understand correctly, it is a distributive property. Like in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/283789/571273). Then, in this case, it should have an $=$ sign, not $\subseteq$. 
But exercise also asks to show that there is no equality here.

**Update:** Here is a quote from book: "Show that in first formula we cannot replace $\subseteq$ by $=$."

Comment: For two sets $A,B$, $A=B\iff A\subseteq B\wedge B\subseteq A$.

Comment: You shouldn't see $\bigcup S$ as $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \dots \cup S_n$ as the union can be infinite!

Comment: @Math_QED Are you suggesting, that we can not put $=$ sign there in case of infinite sets?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the union can run over an infinite index set, while you seem to think that you can index it over the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ which is finite.

Comment: I just ran into this in the same book, and I’m as confused as you are... Did you ever find an authoritative answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Then it should have an $=$ sign, not $⊆$. But exercise also asks to show, that you can not put equality here.

No, $\subseteq$ is not the same as $\subset$ or more clearly $\subsetneq$ .   Just as, $\leq$ is not the same as $\lt$ or more clearly $\lneq$ .

To prove $\sf A=B$ you must prove $\sf A\subseteq B$ and $\sf A\supseteq B$.   All the exercise is asking is for you to prove the former and just not worry about whether or not the other is true.

Comment: Here is a quote from book : "Show that in first formula we cannot replace $\subseteq$ with ="